Pagination Bar Indicator is Not Synchronize with Banner
so I want to make a carousel and each indicator has an animated progressbar when it is active, but currently the two components are not in sync and I don't know where it is
const CarouselTimer = () => {
  const slidesRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const viewConfig = useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 }).current;

  const progressInterval = useRef(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const loaderValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const load = (progressValue) => {
    Animated.timing(loaderValue, {
      toValue: progressValue,
      duration: 200, // Syncing the duration with the banner change interval
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    load(progress);
    if (progress >= 100) {
      setProgress(0);
    }
  }, [progress]);

  const width = loaderValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    progressInterval.current = setInterval(
      () => setProgress((old) => old + 5),
      200
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(progressInterval.current);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentIndex === carouselData.length - 1) {
        snapTo(0);
      } else {
        snapTo(currentIndex + 1);
      }
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [currentIndex]);

  const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
    setCurrentIndex(viewableItems[0]?.index || 0);
  }).current;

  const snapTo = (index) => {
    if (slidesRef.current) {
      slidesRef.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index });
    }
  };

  const _renderImage = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item?.fullImage }}
          style={{
            width: moderateScale(327),
            height: moderateScale(112),
            borderRadius: moderateScale(8),
            marginHorizontal: moderateScale(4)
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  const _renderAnimatedPaginator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: moderateScale(40),
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: Color.skyBlue25,
            borderColor: '#000',
            borderRadius: 5
          }}>
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: Color.skyBlue100,
              height: 8,
              width: width,
              borderRadius: 5
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const _renderPaginator = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: moderateScale(64) }}>
        {carouselData.map((_, i) => {
          const dotWidth = scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: [
              (i - 1) * moderateScale(327),
              i * moderateScale(327),
              (i + 1) * moderateScale(327)
            ],
            outputRange: [10, 40, 10],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
          });

          const opacity = scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: [
              (i - 1) * moderateScale(327),
              i * moderateScale(327),
              (i + 1) * moderateScale(327)
            ],
            outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
          });

          if (i === currentIndex) {
            return _renderAnimatedPaginator();
          }

          return (
            <Pressable key={i.toString()} onPress={() => snapTo(i)}>
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  width: dotWidth,
                  height: moderateScale(8),
                  borderRadius: moderateScale(5),
                  marginHorizontal: moderateScale(4),
                  opacity,
                  backgroundColor: Color.skyBlue100
                }}
              />
            </Pressable>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const _renderCarousel = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          ref={slidesRef}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingHorizontal: moderateScale(24),
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginTop: moderateScale(48)
          }}
          data={carouselData}
          renderItem={_renderImage}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          bounces={false}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
            { useNativeDriver: false }
          )}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
          viewabilityConfig={viewConfig}
          scrollEventThrottle={32}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginTop: moderateScale(4)
          }}>
          {_renderPaginator()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return <View style={styles.containers}>{_renderCarousel()}</View>;
};


Expecting the banner and the paginator is synchronize with the timer, and and every time the page is called, the banner runs first and the indicator animation doesn't start yet
